# How to make element hide on scroll down and appear on scroll up using JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a header component that is made up of two levels of navigation:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.skinny-banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav {
  min-height: 112px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.dummy-content {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="skinny-banner">Skinny banner that should hide when scrolling down and appear when scrolling up</div>
  <div class="main-nav">Should always be visible and should pin to top when skinny banner is hidden</div>
</div>
<div class="dummy-content"></div>
```

How can I ensure that the skinny banner hides when the user scrolls down, and becomes visible again when scrolling up whilst ensuring that the main-nav remains sticky to the top when the skinny banner is hidden?

I'd like to avoid using JQuery and using vanilla JS/CSS.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to set the `position: sticky` and `top: 0` to the `.main-nav` element, not the `.header-container` element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.skinny-banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav {
  min-height: 112px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.dummy-content {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="skinny-banner">Skinny banner that should hide when scrolling down and appear when scrolling up</div>
  <div class="main-nav">Should always be visible and should pin to top when skinny banner is hidden</div>
  <div class="dummy-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey! thanks for this, can I ask why when I remove the `dummy-content` div from within the header, this no longer works? 

To be more accurate, I've updated my OP to have the `dummy-content` sitting outside of the `header-container`